# javascript not working when loading a modal remotely

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code that loads a modal remotely heres the code:

```
$('.empty').on('click', function(e){
    var event = $(this).data('event');
    var user = $(this).data('user');
    $('.modal-content').load('emptyEvent.php', { "date": event, "user": user },function(result){
    $('#fullModal').modal({show:true});
    });
});
```

Then in that page emptyEvent.php I have a timepicker the html is:

```
<input name="start" id="timepicker1" type="text" class="form-control">
```

and the javascript is:

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker({
    minuteStep: 15,
    defaultTime: '8:00',
    showMeridian: false
});
```

When I dont load the file remotely, say I went on emptyEvent.php normally, the datepicker works, but as soon as its loaded remotely it doesnt. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

load() will remove any content in the html target before appending the contents of the load response.

Comment: my javascript is in the file im loading

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world it should work, I have used load quite a lot, however, I suggest to set the timepicker after the content was loaded, like this:

```
$('.modal-content').load('emptyEvent.php', { "date": event, "user": user },function(result){
$('#timepicker1').timepicker({
minuteStep: 15,
defaultTime: '8:00',
showMeridian: false
});
$('#fullModal').modal({show:true});
```

and of course remove it from your emptyEvent.php, it is much more healthier, and also watch the console, see if there isn't any error message.

Comment: Based on what you have provided, it should work, I assume you are using jQuery and jQueryUI (or bootstrap), may sound stupid, but make sure that you load the framework in the main file and there is no reference to it in emptyEvent.php at all